# Average subtracted of max and min returns wrong result

Tags: c, sum, max, average, min

I want to find the average of 5 numbers apart from the max and min of the table.

Nevertheless the following code provides the wrong result.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

#define size 5

main() {
  int i;
  float table[size], max, min, mo, sum;
  max = 0;
  min = 0;
  mo = 0;

  printf("Provide a number: ");
  scanf("%f", &table[1]);
  max = table[1];
  min = table[1];

  for (i = 2; i <= size; i++) {
    printf("Provide a number: ");
    scanf("%f", &table[i]);

    if (max <= table[i])
      max = table[i];
    if (min >= table[i]) {
      min = table[i];
    }
    sum = sum + table[i];
  }

  mo = (sum - max - min) / (size - 2);
  printf("The average numberis: %f", mo);
}
```

Example:

If you input 1,2,3,4,5 the output will be 2,666667 instead of 3.

Could you please advise why this is happening?

Comment: To start, arrays have 0-based indexes, so you're writing out of bounds of `table`.

Comment: IOW: `table[1]` -> `table[0]` and `for (i=2; i<=size; i++)` -> `for (i = 1; i < size; i++)`. And you don't initialize `sum`.

Comment: OT: It's very awkward to treat the first input as a special case. You'd better separate input from the actual computation. First do the only the input, then have a second for loop that does the computation. And you also should indent your code properly (I've done it for you)

Comment: Apart from what has been mentioned: the sum does not include the first array element. You need to learn how to debug programs, either by using a debugger or at least by printing the content of relevant variables at strategic places in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution!! I have made the changes you proposed and it works!
The reason I treated the first input as a special case is that I wanted to set the min and max with the first value of the table in order to implement the if inside the for loop

Comment: @el_noobito Curious, in `if (max <= table[i]) max = table[i];`, why assign `max` when `max == table[i]`?

Comment: @el_noobito Given "apart from the max and min of the table", if input was `1, 10, 20, 100, 100`, do you expect the average to be (10 + 20 + 100)/3 or (10 + 20)/2?  Note the max appears twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited the code based on the comments and it word properly. Thank you very much!

```
#include <stdio.h> 

#define size 5

main() {
  int i;
  float table[size], max, min, mo, sum;
  max = 0;
  min = 0;
  mo = 0;

  printf("Provide a number: ");
  scanf("%f", &table[0]);
  max = table[0];
  min = table[0];
  sum = table[0];

  for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    printf("Provide a number: ");
    scanf("%f", &table[i]);

    if (max <= table[i])
      max = table[i];
    if (min >= table[i]) {
      min = table[i];
    }
    sum = sum + table[i];
  }

  mo = (sum - max - min) / (size - 2);
  printf("The average numberis: %f", mo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following modified code works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define size 5

void main()
{
   int i=0, count=0;
   float table[size], max, min, sum=0, avg;

   //read all five numbers
   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       printf("Provide a number: ");
       scanf("%f", &table[i]);
   }

   //find max and min
   max = table[0];
   min = table[0];
   for (i = 1; i < size; i++)
   {
      if(max < table[i])
       max = table[i];

      if(min > table[i])
       min = table[i];
   }

   //calculate sum and average leaving the max and min
   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       if((table[i] != max) && (table[i] != min))
       {
           sum = sum + table[i];
           count++;
       }
   }
   avg = sum/count;

   printf("\r\nThe average number is: %f", avg);


}
```

`

Comment: Interesting that this code exempts all occurrences of min and max.

Comment: Minor: idea `if(min > table[i]) min = table[i];` to `else if(min > table[i]) min = table[i];`